# CUDA 5.0 cuda-gdb on Linux Needs dedicated CPU?

Tags: cuda, cuda-gdb

With a fresh CUDA 5.0 Linux install on CentOS 5.5, I am not able to gdb. So I am wondering if you still need a dedicated GPU for the Linux cuda-gdb?  I tried it with the Vesa device driver for X11, but get the same result. Profiling works, running the app works, but trying to run cuda-gdb gives :

> warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x2aaaaaaab000

Any suggestions?

Comment: I assume that title should read GPU?

Answer (score 1):

cuda-gdb still needs a GPU that is not used by graphical environment (e.g. if you are running Gnome/KDE/etc. you need to have system with several GPUs - not necessary all of them must be NVIDIA GPUs)

This particular message is not about this problem - you can ignore it. cuda-gdb will tell if it fails because no GPU can be used for debugging.